# Is there an equivalent of Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy in REST API or .Net SDK?

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net, azure-keyvault

I need to programmatically permission Azure Key Vault and the closest I got to it is `Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy` PowerShell command.

Is there an equivalent in the .NET SDK for that or perhaps in the REST API?

Comment: For future reference, PowerShell uses the REST APIs. If there is a PS command for it, there is *definitely* a REST endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

[here you go](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/vaults#Vaults_CreateOrUpdate), you could probably find something similar for the .NET SDK.

Also, if you do `Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -debug` you would find the information needed:

```
DEBUG: ============================ HTTP REQUEST ============================

HTTP Method:
PUT

Absolute Uri:
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/xxx?api-version=2015-06-01

Body {Omitted}
```

edit: For future reference, PowerShell uses the REST APIs. If there is a PS command for it, there is definitely a REST endpoint. By Junnas

Answer (score 0):

We can use [Microsoft Azure Key Vault Management](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.KeyVault/2.0.0-preview)  to do that.It is a **preview** version. We can create or update Key Vault using keyVaultManagementClient.Vaults.CreateOrUpdateAsync() function.
I did a demo for it. My detail steps are as following:

**Prerequisites:**

Registry an App in Azure AD and create service principle for it. More detail steps please refer to [document](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_stranger/2016/10/21/using-the-azure-arm-rest-apin-get-access-token/).

**Steps:**

1.Create a C# console application

2.Add the demo code in the project

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.KeyVault;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.KeyVault.Models;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using Microsoft.Rest;

var subscriptionId = "Your Subscription Id";
var clientId = "Your Registry Application Id";
var tenantId = "Your tenant Id";
var secretKey = "Application secret Key";
var objectId = "Registry Application object Id"
var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, secretKey);
var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + tenantId);
const string resourceGroupName = "tom";
// The name of the vault to create.
const string vaultName = "TomNewKeyVaultForTest";

var accessPolicy = new AccessPolicyEntry
{
   ApplicationId = Guid.Parse(clientId),
   TenantId = Guid.Parse(tenantId),
   Permissions = new Permissions
   {
      Keys = new List<string> { "List","Get" },
      Secrets = new List<string> { "All" }
       },
      ObjectId = Guid.Parse(objectId)
    };

    VaultProperties vaultProps = new VaultProperties
    {
        EnabledForTemplateDeployment = true,
        TenantId = Guid.Parse(tenantId),
        AccessPolicies = new List<AccessPolicyEntry>
        {
            accessPolicy
        }
     };
     Microsoft.Rest.ServiceClientCredentials credentials = new TokenCredentials(token);
     VaultCreateOrUpdateParameters vaultParams = new VaultCreateOrUpdateParameters("eastasia", vaultProps);

     KeyVaultManagementClient keyVaultManagementClient= new KeyVaultManagementClient(credentials)
     {
         SubscriptionId = subscriptionId
     };

     var result = keyVaultManagementClient.Vaults.CreateOrUpdateAsync(resourceGroupName, vaultName, vaultParams).Result;
```

3.Debug the demo

[image]

4.Check the created or updated KeyVault in the azure portal

[image]

More SDK information please refer to the package.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Hyak.Common" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Common" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Common.Dependencies" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.KeyVault" version="2.0.0-preview" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.9" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Async" version="1.0.168" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.14" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="2.28.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.22" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime" version="2.3.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure" version="3.3.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```